# How can I display the 'Send to' and 'Open With' context menus?

Tags: windows, delphi, winapi, windows-shell

Some time ago I asked about [how to pop up the Windows context (right-click) menu for a certain file in Delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1581975/how-to-pop-up-the-windows-context-menu-for-a-given-file-using-delphi). However, even if everything works (almost) OK, the 'Send to...' and 'Open with...' submenus don't have any items, even if when I right-click in Explorer on the same file name they work OK. (For example, 'Send to...' has 'Desktop (create shotcut)', 'Email recipient' etc.).

How can I make those menus appear?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Raymond Chen wrote about this precise problem a few years ago in a many-part series about hosting a context menu. The key theme to his articles was that as you read the documentation, you have to remember that *your* program is playing the part of the shell, whereas the documentation is normally written from the perspective of the code implementing the context-menu interfaces, as opposed to the code calling them.

As early as [part 2](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040922-00/?p=37793), Chen observed that the send-to and open-with menus appear empty. [Part 5](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040927-00/?p=37733) addresses your immediate concern about those submenus. The answer is that you need to **handle menu messages**. There is a window handle associated with your menu — the handle you provided to `TrackPopupMenuEx` (`HND` in [Issam's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1581975/how-to-pop-up-the-windows-context-menu-for-a-given-file-using-delphi/1587130#1587130) to your question). That window will receive messages while the menu is active, and it needs to forward them to the objects implementing the menu commands. The window has a window procedure, and that's where you need to call the menu interface's `HandleMenuMsg` and `HandleMenuMsg2` methods. The article has an example.

Other parts of the article series cover the other things that you no-doubt alluded to when you said your menu "almost" works. [Part 3](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040923-00/?p=37773) talks about where the property dialog appears. [Part 7](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040930-00/?p=37693) s about invoking the default verb. I suggest you read the entire series. Don't fear that everything's in C++; it's almost all interface methods and API functions, so it should translate to Delphi without much trouble.