# Showing Explorer Menu in Delphi

Tags: delphi, menu, explorer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to pop-up the Windows context menu for a given file using Delphi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1581975/how-to-pop-up-the-windows-context-menu-for-a-given-file-using-delphi)

Hello. In Delphi, we can use TShellListView to show files in a component like windows explorer. When i click on an icon in it, it shows a popup menu same as windows explorer. Can i show same menu automatically without using TShellListView?

Example i will write a function like;

ShowFileMenu( 'c:\file.txt' );

and it will show that file's windows explorer menu.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm sure it's possible to re-create this behavior (someone wrote wrappers for those API calls) but doing so would be a LOT of work to create and maintain.  Perhaps you could be more explicit in the specification you're trying to address (e.g. are you allowed any dependency on third-party code, or are you just trying to limit cost?).

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1581975/how-to-pop-up-the-windows-context-menu-for-a-given-file-using-delphi. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2040659/how-can-i-display-the-send-to-and-open-with-context-menus

Answer (score 3):

I have answered question like this before.
see:

[How to pop-up the Windows context menu for a given file using Delphi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1581975/how-to-pop-up-the-windows-context-menu-for-a-given-file-using-delphi)

I hope it will help you.