# Show the default right-click menu - Delphi

Tags: delphi, properties, menu, right-click

I have a Listbox which contain a list of files . can i access the Windows right-click menu in the listbox to access the open , properties , delete and rename items ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Kermia check the [`JclShell`](http://www.koders.com/delphi/fid8C12864D2AABD50B060876ED04A3F2219A90F7CA.aspx?s=hook) unit from the JEDI JCL library, inside of this unit exist a function called  `DisplayContextMenu` which show the context menu associated to a file. this function encapsulate the calls to the IContextMenu interface and makes your work more easy.

```
function DisplayContextMenu(const Handle: HWND; const FileName: string;
  Pos: TPoint): Boolean;
```

Comment: +1 What do you pass as the Handle parameter? What is it used for?

Comment: @David you can pass the handle of your form, this handle is used in the `IContextMenu.InvokeCommand` which receive a `CMINVOKECOMMANDINFO` Structure http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773215%28v=vs.85%29.aspx.

Comment: @Kernia, this unit is part of the JCL (Jedi Code Library). you can download the latest version from here http://wiki.delphi-jedi.org/index.php?title=JEDI_Code_Library

Comment: Wow ! That's what i wanted exactly . Thank you so much Mr Pirooz .

Comment: @RRUZ, the DisplayContextMenu() seems nice for one file, but what about multiple files and folders from different local drives?

Answer (score 5):

Check the [IContextMenu](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776095%28VS.85%29.aspx) interface. But be aware that Windows shell doesn't identify its objects by filename - actually they could not be files. It uses a concatenation of ids, and you may need to get what item id list a file is assigend to before invoking some shell functions on it.

Comment: That looks like it allows you to enumerate what the shell regards as being in the context menu. As I read it, you'd still need to populate the menu yourself, and then invoke commands through this interface in response to Delphi OnClick events. Is that correct?

Comment: +1 Certainly looks like a good way to implement OnClick handlers.

Comment: Yes, you have to create the menu (at least it allows you to use any kind of menu you prefer), anyway it gives you the command each element supports, and let you invoke the proper command as defined by the shell. It doesn't work on files only either, although that's beyond the user question.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an implementation example using the 'OnContextPopup' event of a list box, which is populated with file names in the project directory, to launch the shortcut menu of a file when right-clicked on its name:

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    ListBox1: TListBox;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure ListBox1ContextPopup(Sender: TObject; MousePos: TPoint;
      var Handled: Boolean);
  private
  protected
    procedure WndProc(var Msg: TMessage); override;
  public
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

uses
  shlobj, comobj;

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  SearchRec: TSearchRec;
begin
  ListBox1.Clear;

  // populate list box with files in the project folder
  if FindFirst(ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName) + '*.*',
               0, SearchRec) = 0 then
    repeat
      ListBox1.Items.Add(SearchRec.Name);
    until FindNext(SearchRec) <> 0;
  FindClose(SearchRec);
end;

var
  // Required to handle messages for owner drawn items, as in 'SendTo' menu.
  // Also used as a flag in WndProc to know if we're tracking a shortcut menu.
  ContextMenu2: IContextMenu2 = nil;

procedure TForm1.ListBox1ContextPopup(Sender: TObject; MousePos: TPoint;
  var Handled: Boolean);
var
  Item: Integer;
  DeskFolder, Folder: IShellFolder;
  Eaten, Attributes: ULONG;
  pIdl, FolderpIdl: PItemIDList;
  ContextMenu: IContextMenu;
  Menu: HMENU;
  Pos: TPoint;
  Cmd: DWORD;
  CommandInfo: TCMInvokeCommandInfo;
begin
  Item := (Sender as TListBox).ItemAtPos(MousePos, True);
  Handled := Item <> -1;
  if not Handled then
    Exit;
  TListBox(Sender).ItemIndex := Item;

  // IShellFolder for Desktop folder (root)
  OleCheck(SHGetDesktopFolder(DeskFolder));

  // Item ID List for the folder that the file is in
  Attributes := 0;
  OleCheck(DeskFolder.ParseDisplayName(Handle, nil,
                    PWideChar(WideString(ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName))),
                    Eaten, FolderpIdl, Attributes));

  // IShellFolder for the folder the file is in
  OleCheck(DeskFolder.BindToObject(FolderpIdl, nil, IID_IShellFolder, Folder));
  CoTaskMemFree(FolderpIdl);

  // Item ID List for the file, relative to the folder it is in
  Attributes := 0;
  OleCheck(Folder.ParseDisplayName(Handle, nil,
           PWideChar(WideString(ExtractFileName(TListBox(Sender).Items[Item]))),
           Eaten, pIdl, Attributes));

  // IContextMenu for the relative Item ID List
  OleCheck(Folder.GetUIObjectOf(Handle, 1, pIdl, IID_IContextMenu,
                                  nil, ContextMenu));
  CoTaskMemFree(pIdl);

  Menu := CreatePopupMenu;
  try
    // Populate our menu with shortcut items
    OleCheck(ContextMenu.QueryContextMenu(Menu, 0, 1, $7FFF, CMF_EXPLORE));

    // ContextMenu2 used in WndProc
    ContextMenu.QueryInterface(IID_IContextMenu2, ContextMenu2);
    try
      Pos := TWinControl(Sender).ClientToScreen(MousePos);
      // launch the menu
      Bool(Cmd) := TrackPopupMenu(Menu,
                            TPM_LEFTBUTTON or TPM_RIGHTBUTTON or TPM_RETURNCMD,
                            Pos.X, Pos.Y, 0, Handle, nil);
    finally
      // clear so that we don't intervene every owner drawn menu item message in
      // WndProc
      ContextMenu2 := nil;
    end;

    // Invoke command if we have one
    if Bool(Cmd) then begin
      FillChar(CommandInfo, SizeOf(CommandInfo), 0);
      CommandInfo.cbSize := SizeOf(CommandInfo);
      CommandInfo.hwnd := Handle;
      CommandInfo.lpVerb := MakeIntResource(Cmd - 1);
      CommandInfo.nShow := SW_SHOWNORMAL;

      OleCheck(ContextMenu.InvokeCommand(CommandInfo));
    end;

  finally
    DestroyMenu(Menu);
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.WndProc(var Msg: TMessage);
begin
  if ((Msg.Msg = WM_INITMENUPOPUP) or (Msg.Msg = WM_DRAWITEM)
              or (Msg.Msg = WM_MEASUREITEM)) and Assigned(ContextMenu2) then
    ContextMenu2.HandleMenuMsg(Msg.Msg, Msg.WParam, Msg.LParam)
  else
    inherited;
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend looking at something like [tpShellShock](http://tpshellshock.sourceforge.net/) when you want to show shell like controls in your Delphi app. It offers tree views, list views etc. that can be connected together much like an Explorer Windows. It will display the appropriate icons for the files. I'm sure it offers the facilities you talk about too.

It might need some porting work if you are on a modern Unicode Delphi, but when I have done that it proved relatively straightforward.

No doubt there are other libraries that offer shell controls, this is just the one I am familiar with.

Otherwise if you want to stick with your current solution it's easiest to implement your own menu actions. Open and Properties are just simple calls to ShellExecute with the appropriate verb. Delete is a call to DeleteFile and Rename is a call to MoveFile.

Comment: Your post reads like you have made tpShellShock unicode compatible? Would there be any possibility to publish this somewhere?

Comment: I tried to use your solution in my application, but in order to make it work I needed to change one line:

CommandInfo.lpVerb := MakeIntResourceA(Cmd - 1);

I had to change MakeIntResource ro MakeIntResourceA as lpVerb seems to be declared as AnsiString, at least the compiler says so and the declaration reads so when followed the souce code. Is there some newer declaration available for CommandInfo or was this simply a slight oversight in your code like the lack of ActiveX unit in uses? Other than that it works really good, thanks for sharing this!

Comment: @markus There's no code in my answer, you commented on the wro G answer. You don't want to use A suffix functions as a rule though. I suggest reading up on Unicode.

Comment: Sorry to "missattribute" the post at you.

Yes I don't want to use api calls with A suffix. But the field where this was assigned to was/is declared as Ansi as it looks like. I didn't spot what else to do on the first look. I might revisit this later on in the project.