# Adding "Paste" to the Shell Context Menu

Tags: delphi, shell, contextmenu

I am using this routine to pop up the Shell Context Menu for a file name which is working well, except for one thing.

[How to pop-up the Windows context menu for a given file using Delphi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1581975/how-to-pop-up-the-windows-context-menu-for-a-given-file-using-delphi)

When I click "Copy" the menu closes as expected. If I move to another Folder or stay in the same one, when I right-click again for the Context Menu, it has no "Paste" option. Not even a grayed out one. I checked on the Poster's blog as mentioned in his Edit at the bottom, but that new routine crashes with Incorrect Parameter.

Can someone please assist with adding "Paste" to the original routine in the above link

Thanks

Comment: *Files* don't have a "Paste" option. It's *directories* that have that option. See for yourself in Windows Explorer.

Comment: Does that code actually make sure the file is copied?

Answer (score 0):

Look for TClipboard (library/uses ClipBrd). Using this you can manage a cliboard on Delphi.

More information: [Basic CLipboard Operations](http://delphi.about.com/od/vclusing/a/tclipboard.htm)

Obs.: You can use "Actions" too, depending your needs. See ActionManager component, and Action properties of your popupmenu.